# Getting errors trying to use KeyListeners and ImageIcons?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, stack-overflow, imageicon

I am currently trying to make a maze game for school, and I am confused as to why I am getting these errors. Here are the pieces of code that are involved. Also everything that is needed to be imported has been imported. First is the Player class which has the player's location, and then their image.

```
public class Player {
int playerX;
int playerY;
int moveSpeed = 5; //I can edit move speed here
Image character;

//getters and setters to utilize the player's location and image
public Player(){ //constructor for initial starting points
    playerX = 50;
    playerY = 50;
    ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("E://Workspace//Maze//images//Player.jpg");
    character = player.getImage();
}

public void setPlayerX(int playerX){
    this.playerX = playerX;
}
public int getPlayerX(){
    return playerX;
}

public void setPlayerY(int playerY){
    this.playerY = playerY;
}
public int getPlayerY(){
    return playerY;
}

public void setMoveSpeed(int moveSpeed){
    this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
}
public int getMoveSpeed(){
    return moveSpeed;
}

public Image getPlayerImage(){
    return character;
}
}
```

Now is the layout class which creates the JPanel, and is supposed to be what ends up drawing the player image into the game, and is also what is supposed to allow the player to move.

```
public class Layout extends JPanel implements ActionListener { //GUI with a      non null FlowLayout
Player p = new Player();
Maze m = new Maze();

//500 x 500 seemed like a good size for the maze game
int x = 500;
int y = 500;

public Layout(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    addKeyListener(new Move());
    setFocusable(true);
}

//for use in setting and getting the borders of the game
public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public void paintGame(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), p.getPlayerX(), p.getPlayerY(), null);
}
@Overrride
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    repaint();
}
}

class Move extends Layout implements KeyListener { //Inheritance
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) { //for the movement in the game
    //I used both keys so that if the player woukld like to use WASD or the    arrow keys either will work
    if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || press.getKeyCode() ==  KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        //move up
        p.setPlayerY(p.getPlayerY() - p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        //move down
        p.setPlayerY(p.getPlayerY() + p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        //move left
        p.setPlayerX(p.getPlayerX() - p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
    else if(press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D || press.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        //move right
        p.setPlayerX(p.getPlayerX() + p.getMoveSpeed());
    }
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
    //nothing is needed here
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //does nothing if a key is type (no need for it)
}
}
```

Lastly is the Play class which is supposed to run the game (currently I am just trying to get the player to move across a blank space without the map implemented yet).

```
public class Play {
public static void main(String[]args) { 
    play();
}

public static void play(){
    Layout l = new Layout();
    Player p = new Player();
    Maze m = new Maze();

    l.setSize(l.getX(), l.getY()); //size can be changed in layout
    l.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Now for some reason I am getting a multitude of errors when I try to run this. I am hoping to get this fixed soon so I can start on implementing my maze map. Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ref.SoftReference.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.SoftCache$ValueCell.strip(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.SoftCache$ValueCell.access$300(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.SoftCache.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at mazeGame.Player.<init>(Player.java:16)
at mazeGame.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:11)
at mazeGame.Move.<init>(Layout.java:49)
at mazeGame.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:20)
```

The: `at mazeGame.Move.<init>(Layout.java:49)
    at mazeGame.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:20)` continues on for atleast 20 lines before Eclipse stops outputing the errors.
Please help me solve this as I am currently stuck on how to get the Player to move, and need to start on creating the map for the maze. Sorry for the really long post, but I wanted to post anything that could possibly be giving me the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have infinite recursion in your constructors. `Layout()` calls `addKeyListener(new Move());`, and `Move` extends `Layout`, so `Move`'s constructor also calls `Layout()`, which in turn calls `Move()`.

You need to refactor your code to avoid that. A simple approach would be making *Move not extend Layout*, and passing player as a constructor parameter to `Move`.

```
class Move implements KeyListener {
    final Player p;
    Move(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    ...
}
```

and in `Layout`:

```
addKeyListener(new Move(p));
```

Also consider using [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a key listener. It's often a better approach.

Comment: Well now it runs, how ever it runs for about a few seconds, and then terminates. No java screen shows up or anything, so now I am unable to actually play the game, and test the characters movement.

Comment: Ok so I changed it to JFrame, however now I am getting just a blank screen with nothing is being drawn...

Comment: @user1234 I can't tell for certain what is wrong, as I don't have the relevant code -the question has nothing about `JFrames` whatsoever. The visible code is not calling `repaint()` from any relevant location (that should be likely done after movement), also for the panel to draw itself correctly with `repaint()` it should override `paintComponent()`. See [custom painting in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details.

Comment: I changed it back to JPanel and now nothing pops up, not even a Java box with a title and a blank gray screen. Also I am unable to use repaint() in Move. However I did add a @Override (I edited the code), and hopefully I used that right.

Comment: @user1234 If you meant you changed `Layout` to extend `JFrame`, that's unnecessary. Just create a `JFrame` and `add()` the `Layout` panel there (and then `setVisible(true)` the frame). A panel alone does not display itself, it needs to be in a a window. (with the `paintComponent()` overridden, and calling `repaint()` from somewhere (where exactly, depends on your needs. For many games calling from a timer would be more appropriate than from the key listener))

Comment: How would I add the JPanel into the play() that is the class Play? Right now I have l.add(jpanel); and I am getting errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Something like: `JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Game"); frame.add(new Layout()); frame.setVisible(true)` should work for adding a `Layout` panel to a window, and showing it. (This does not yet correctly set the preferred size, but that's not the most immediate concern).

Comment: Ok I got it to work, however the player image is still not showing up.

Comment: @user1234 did you override `paintComponent()` in `Layout`? It should look roughly like `@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); g.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), p.getPlayerX(), p.getPlayerY(), this); }`.

Comment: Ok I changed the @Override to above paintComponent, and changed paintComponent to protected. I even changed null to this. HOwever it is still not printing the image on the JPanel. Is there a certain way I would have to add it to the JPanel?

Comment: @user1234 Be sure to call `super.paintComponent(g)` instead of `super.paint(g)`.

Comment: This is what I have                                                                              @Override //so it can repaint as needed
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(p.getPlayerImage(), p.getPlayerX(), p.getPlayerY(), this);
 }
 
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
  repaint();
 } and it is still not working

Comment: I can not tell where exactly the code is wrong - that snippet looks fine, so the problem must be elsewhere. [Here](http://pastebin.com/zyntmAkN) is a very simple, runnable example of a `JPanel` using custom drawing, and including and displaying it inside a frame. Please take a look and check where your code differs.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. It is still not working but I can mess around with it some more using the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace lines:

```
ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("E://Workspace//Maze//images//Player.jpg");
character = player.getImage();
```

with:

```
character = ImageIO.read(new File("E://Workspace//Maze//images//Player.jpg"));
```

I believe that problem could be cause by async loading of ImageIcon (The image will be preloaded by using MediaTracker to monitor the loading state of the image.) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: When I did that I got an error, however when I kept my old one it worked. I am not sure why (I was getting the IOException error).